# Fullpage.js compatibility with charts.js

Tags: html, css, position, fullpage.js, chart.js

I am using charts.js and fullpage.js

I think that the navigation dots are pushing my chart to the left. Is there any way to remove this?

CSS

```
.section {
text-align: center;
}

.content {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 10%;
}

 #canvas {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
padding-top: 2%;

}

.chart {
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id='fullpage'>
<div class='section' id='section0'>
    <div class='slide'>
        <div class='content' id='benchmark'>
            <h1>Performance vs Benchmark</h1>
                <div class='chart'>
                    <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Also, in the fullpage CSS, I set the navigation arrows to display:none, but they appear when I include a chart (they are hidden otherwise).

Thank you.

Comment: Which version of fullPage.js are you using?

Comment: The newest one. I decided to just delete all of the CSS for the arrows, but I would be interested if there was another way to hide them.

Comment: Just overwritting its style `fp-controlArrow` and using `display:none`